# Mouseover image reveal pushes text despite z-Index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have my code set up so when you hover over the H2 an image is revealed. Hypothetically, because the text is z-index:2 and the image is z-index:1, the H2 text should stay fixed. However, upon mouseover, the text is still being moved down to make room for the image.

I need the text to stay fixed in the same position and the background image to just appear upon hover without nudging the h2.

You can view the test here:
http://www.rorywolfseydel.com/test3-2

```css
h2 {
  line-height: 68px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 0 !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 12;
}

.artisthover {
  display: none
}

h2.two:hover img {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -250px
}

h2.two a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

h2.three:hover img {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-right: -250px
}

h2.three a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h2 class="two">
    <a href="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/artists/absolutelyfree">ABSOLUTELY FREE</a>
    <img src="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/2019artists/absolutelyfree.jpg" class="artisthover" width="500px">
  </h2>
</center>

<center>
  <h2 class="three">
    <a href="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/artists/badgeepoqueensemble">BADGE EPOQUE ensemble</a>
    <img src="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/2019artists/badgeepoque.jpg" class="artisthover" width="500px">
  </h2>
</center>
```

Comment: Your test link will never work for us because it is a WP preview link and only logged in users can see that.

Comment: of course, here is the published: http://www.rorywolfseydel.com/test3-2

Answer (score 0):

*Hypothetically, because the text is z-index:2 and the image is z-index:1, the H2 text should stay fixed.* This is an incorrect assumption on how `z-index` works.

`z-index` is stacking order of elements, having a higher or lower `z-index` does not mean that elements with a higher `z-index` will automatically appear on top of each other. You need to use `position` for that.

For instance, two elements with different `z-index` values, but with position relative, are positioned relative to one another - meaning the elements affect each other's positioning, even if one has a higher or lower z-index.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.top {
  height: 200px;
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.top:hover {
  z-index: 3;
}

.bottom {
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">

</div>

<div class="bottom">

</div>
```

As you can see, the elements have different `z-index` values, but the position is `relative`. If you hover the top `div`, you can see the `box-shadow` overlapping the bottom `div`, but the position of the elements does not change in regards to top, right, bottom, left - only the stacking order.

Now for your specific example:

Here we use `position: absolute` to take the `img` element out of the document flow, allowing you to take advantage of `z-index`. Since the image is now out of document flow, it no longer affects any other element around it.

The snippet below is a very simple demonstration with the `position` changed on the image. It probably doesn't look how you want it to, but it's a starting point.

Couple other things:

1. The `<center>` tag is obsolete. You should use `text-align: center` on the `h2` instead.
2. Depending on your end goal for how you want it to look, I would consider moving the image out of the `h2` tags and wrapping the `h2` and `img` in a containing element (e.g. `div`). This will allow for better control over the placement of the image once it's visible.

```css
h2 {
  line-height: 68px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 0 !important;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 12;
  text-align: center;
}

.artisthover {
  display: none
}

h2.two:hover img {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -250px
}

h2.two a {
  color: #000;
}

h2.three:hover img {
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-right: -250px
}

h2.three a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="two">
  <a href="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/artists/absolutelyfree">ABSOLUTELY FREE</a>
  <img src="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/2019artists/absolutelyfree.jpg" class="artisthover" width="">
</h2>

<h2 class="three">
  <a href="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/artists/badgeepoqueensemble">BADGE EPOQUE ensemble</a>
  <img src="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/2019artists/badgeepoque.jpg" class="artisthover" width="500px">
</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.artisthover {
  display: none
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
h2.two:hover img {
  display:inline ;

}
h2.three:hover img {
display:inline ;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<center>
  <h2 class="two">
    <a href="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/artists/absolutelyfree">ABSOLUTELY FREE</a>
    <img src="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/2019artists/absolutelyfree.jpg" class="artisthover" width="500px">
  </h2>
</center>

<center>
  <h2 class="three">
    <a href="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/artists/badgeepoqueensemble">BADGE EPOQUE ensemble</a>
    <img src="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/2019artists/badgeepoque.jpg" class="artisthover" width="500px">
  </h2>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, to set z-index on the image, the position has to be absolute for the image to stay the same, as well as the display of the outer element be inline....